# is the mind naturally conditioned to visualize the worst case to keep the body safe?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, dreams, visualization

Mind has the ability to visualize something dangerous to keep the body safe, I would like to know are humans naturally built in such a way or do we learn to do so as we grow?

I have found that visualization of a scenario that is fearful will make the mind fear and vice versa when you visualize something nice. But the purpose of this question is to find out what makes the mind visualize fear as most of the non-voluntary action that happens in the mind.